# Particle Filter for structural credit risk model

Tags: hidden-markov-model, particle-filter, sequential-monte-carlo

Kwon (2012)* proposes a structural credit risk model where the asset value process and the noise are estimated based on the observed equity prices:

[image]

- $S$ - equity prices
- $V$ - value of the assets
- $Z$ - noise which contaminates the equity prices.

The assumed model for the log equity price is: 
$$\ln S_t = g_S(V_t,t,\Theta_V) + Z_t$$
with $g_S$ being some function of $V_t$ (value of firm's assets at time $t$), $t$ (time) and $\Theta_V$ (parameters governing the asset dynamics)

$V_t$ and $Z_t$ are modeled as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
     dV_t &= \mu V_t dt + \sigma_V d W_t^{\mathbb{P}V}\\
     dZ_t &= -\theta_Z Z_t dt + \sigma_Z dW_t^{\mathbb{P}Z}
\end{align}
$$
$W_t^{\mathbb{P}V}$ is assumed to be independent of $W_t^{\mathbb{P}Z}$ ($\mathbb{P}$ denotes the physical or the real-world probability measure).

The author writes:

> In the process of following the particle filter algorithm steps, we
>   confront the problem that re-sampling weight $w^j \approx f_{t+1}\left(S_{t+1}\mid V_{t+1}^{(*j)},Z_{t+1}^{(*j)}\right)$ is a $\delta$-function, which takes only 0
>   and 1 values. In order to solve this problem, the algorithm is
>   adjusted as follows:

[image]

where:

- $J$ is the Jacobian transformation of $Z_t=\ln(S_t)-g(V_t,t,\Theta)$
- $q_{t+1}$ is the density function of $V_{t+1} \mid V_t$
- $k_{t+1}$ is the density function of $Z_{t+1} \mid Z_t$

I don't quite understand how this algorithm solves the "problem" and in particular I don't see why the Jacobian appears in step **(3)**.

My intuition is that since, given $V_{t+1}^{(*j)}$, there is a one-to-one relationship between $S_{t+1}$ and $Z_{t+1}^{(*j)}$, if we were to sample $Z_{t+1}^{(*j)}$ along with $V_{t+1}^{(*j)}$ and evaluate the density function $f_{t+1}\left(S_{t+1}\mid V_{t+1}^{(*j)},Z_{t+1}^{(*j)}\right)$ we would simply get a lot of $0$s (maybe by chance and/or computer rounding error some $1$s).
To sidestep this, we make it look like we've actually sampled the $S_{t+1}$ alongside $V_{t+1}^{(*j)}$ and then evaluate the density of $Z_{t+1}^{(*j)} \mid S_{t+1}, V_{t+1}^{(*j)}$. However, $Z_{t+1}^{(*j)}$ depends on $S_{t+1}$ only through the auto-correlation with $Z_{t}^j$. Therefore we are left with $k_{t+1}(Z_{t+1}^{(*j)}\mid Z_t^j)$ which is a normal distribution according to the properties of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. Not 100% sure of this.

And I'm still confused about step **(3)**. It looks very much like a transformation of variables sorcery.

---

<sub>* Kwon, T. Y. (2012). [Three essays on credit risk models and their Bayesian estimation](https://dash.harvard.edu/handle/1/9288549) (Doctoral dissertation)</sub>

Comment: I would recommend asking this question at the SE Quantitative Finance forum.

Comment: The question is more statistical in nature than "quantic". My guess is that there are more people familiar with Particle Filters here than on quant.stackexchange.com.

Comment: What is f? It is not clear from your post.

Comment: @Forgottenscience I've updated the question with the bit where $f$ appears. So it's just the conditional probability, which would normally (e.g. in the bootstrap filter) serve as the weights.

Comment: @SanduUrsu, if  you change your mind & want this Q migrated to the [quant.SE] SE site, just flag it & let us know.

Comment: The question is indeed a statistical question, I agree that this the correct forum.

Comment: @SanduUrsu this question would be straightforward if you defined clearly on the distributions. Also, the link to the paper doesn't work for me

Comment: @Taylor I have added some details along with my intuition. I think you were right to ask for those details. Mean-reversion might play a role there indeed.
The link takes you to the abstract of the PhD thesis (dash.harvard.edu/handle/1/9288549). On that page there is a link to the pdf.